# Difference that can lead to a wrong interpretation when using density and not bar graph

Tags: r, statistics, bar-chart, histogram, kernel-density

I'm trying to plot the relation between a nominal qualitative variable and a discrete quantitative variable. When I use bar graphs, the amount of Y and N values are consistent. But when I use a density plot, the proportion of Y and N values seems to change, making this plot misleading. Looking at the amount of N values in the bar graph between the score values ​​from 250 to 500, the amount is smaller compared to the same score range in the density graph.
Why does it happen?
[image: Density plot]

[image: Bar plot]

```
 ggplot(pib_date, aes(x = score, fill = first_payment_overdue,         color = first_payment_overdue)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("Y" = "#060606", "N" = "#f5693f")) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("Y" = "#060606",         "N" = "#f5693f")) + geom_density(alpha = 0.4) + labs(title = "Distribuição de score por fpo") + scale_x_continuous("Score", breaks = seq(0, 960, by = 100)) + theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Can you please provide some repeatable data as an example along with your code?

Comment: Looks like the density functions are normalized so that each one has area under the curve equal to 1. That's a conventional way to construct a density, but what you need is to plot w1*density1(x) and w2*density2(x) where w1 + w2 = 1, i.e. w1 is the total mass in density1 and w2 is the total in density2. I don't know how to arrange that in R.

Comment: PS. w1 is just (number of cases in category 1)/(total number of cases), likewise w2 is (number of cases in cat. 2)/(total number of cases).

Comment: @Tourist I guess to make a reproducible example of a density plot I'd have to use pretty much all of my data, wouldn't I?

Comment: Rafael, it would help others help you if you say what is the function call which you used to construct the density plot.

Comment: @RobertDodier 
`ggplot(
    pib_date,
    aes(
        x = score,
        fill = first_payment_overdue,
        color = first_payment_overdue
    )
) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(
        "Y" = "#060606",
        "N" = "#f5693f"
    )) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(
        "Y" = "#060606",
        "N" = "#f5693f"
    )) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.4) +
    labs(title = "Distribuição de score por fpo") +
    scale_x_continuous("Score",
        breaks = seq(0, 960, by = 100)
    ) +
    theme_minimal()`

Comment: Please edit your question to put the code in it. The code isn't for me specifically, it's for everyone.